# How can I log the wrongly formatted XML passed to a Jersey REST server on exception?

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey 2.23 and Moxy XML as a simple REST service.

My services are declared to receive auto generated class from jab from xsd.

When the client is sending wrong xml, I can catch the exception by registering a custom RequestEventListener.

I would like to be able to dump the input xml body fro mthe onEvent method, but I can't find how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

What application server are you using? I know if you're using glass fish you can log into the administrative console and test webservices from there and see all the details in its responses.

Maybe your application server has similar functions

Comment: I am using the Grizzly http server that is provided with Jersey using the artifact jersey-container-grizzly2-http. By the way, I don't search how to dump input on manual tests, but every-times a bad request is done.